# How To Activate H-Bridge?

Tags: hardware, h-bridge

My understanding of the H-bridge is, that activating in1 or in2 will direct the 12V current to the motor, so it either spins right/left. Not that in1 or in2 is the actual current passing through to the 12V motor.

These are the schematics.

I am trying to activate the H-bridge and the 12V motor by powering In1 with digital 2 from my Arduino.

The power outlet is an universal adapter connected to my wall outlet, which then goes to a breadboard power supply.

I don't have a functioning multimeter, so I cannot measure the exact current going through, but I do know, that if I place in1 in the power outlet's Vout the 12V motor spins.

Other than that, I do not have much information, and I would like to ask you guys for help as to why, the 12V motor doesn't spin when I power in1?

[image]

Comment: You don't have a ground connection between the Arduino and the H-bridge?

Comment: @Majenko This is about the dumbest mistake I have made in a long time. Thank you, it needed a common ground.

Comment: It's not a dumb mistake. It's a common mistake. So common I wrote an entire blog article all about it. https://majenko.co.uk/blog/importance-sharing-grounds

Comment: George, you should post a self-answer with the solution and then accept it so the question is marked as answered. (Or @Majenko should post an answer, since they're the one who identified the solution.)

Comment: @DuncanC Will do, I can accept it in 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no common GND between the H-Bridge and the Arduino.

The question has been solved.